# Unable to create a user at django admin panel

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, admin

Well, I'm not really sure that this problem is widespread. When I try to add a user from django's admin panel, I get the error about:

```
The module in NAME could not be imported: django.contrib.main.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator. Check your AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS setting
```

From the body of the mistake I learned that:

```
Exception Value:    
The module in NAME could not be imported: django.contrib.main.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator. Check your AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS setting.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Dmitriy\PycharmProjects\FileTime\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\password_validation.py, line 29, in get_password_validators
```

The main problem is that there's nothing about 'get_password_validators' in that line (29) in that file (password_validation.py). The interesting thing is that I can create a user from command line.

So, what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try to set 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator'? What version of Django do you use?

Comment: @domandinho django version - 3.2.5. Not really understood about setting 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator' :(

Comment: For me you have typo in UserAttributeSimilarityValidator path in AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS in settings.py module as it should start with django.contrib.auth and you have prefix = django.contrib.main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/#enabling-password-validation

I see that this validator is located in `django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator` but from error I see that you entered: `django.contrib.main.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator`

Please open settings.py and set:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
```